# SQL query swap column and row

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, grafana

I would like to know how I can swap the row and column data
It is original data
[image]

I would like to show like this by SQL query
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are wanting one line per distinct `device_id` + `time` combination.

You can do this with some clever uses of the `CASE` command:

```sql
select
  device_id,
  SUM(case when measure_name = 'ntu' then measure_value end) as ntu,
  SUM(case when measure_name = 'shutterspeed' then measure_value end) as shutterspeed,
  SUM(case when measure_name = 'intensity' then measure_value end) as intensity,
  time
from table
group by device_id, time
```

Comment: Yes. You are right. I got data from AWS Timestream. I will try to implement. Thanks!